# Implement approximate $Ry(2\pi /3)$ with gate set {$Rx(\pi),Ry(\pi),Rz(\pi),Rx(\pm \pi/2),Ry(\pm \pi/2),Rz(\pm \pi/2),T,S,H,CZ$}

Tags: quantum-gate

With gate sets {$Rx(\pi),Ry(\pi),Rz(\pi),Rx(\pm \pi/2),Ry(\pm \pi/2),Rz(\pm \pi/2),T,S,H,CZ$}, I want to implement an approximate $2\pi/3$ rotation around Y axis. An ancilla qubit can be used as well. Is there any efficient way to do this?

Comment: to what accuracy?

Comment: The circuit should not be too deep so make it possible to run on a real device. I would give a lower bound around 70% though the higher the better.

Comment: OK, but there's a direct trade-off between depth and accuracy, so if you're asking somebody to go out and compute a specific sequence for you, they need to know what they're aiming for. (Also, Have you evaluated what accuracy you get just using $R_y(\pi/2)$?) Or is it that you want to learn an algorithm for finding a suitable sequence yourself?

Comment: The situation is I need to run a circuit on a real device with just the gate sets mentioned available. In the first step, I have to apply a $Ry(2\pi/3)$ rotation to one qubit.  I am not sure how the accuracy of $Ry(2\pi/3)$ influence the experiment results. So firstly, I need a solution to realize this rotation then I can test and work out the accuracy requirement.

Comment: I'm confused why your gate set is so limited in a NISQ context. Usually the restriction to Clifford+T is for fault tolerant machines, not current machines. In the NISQ context it also imposes a noise floor, since you need longer sequences to be more accurate but longer sequences means more time means more noise means worse result.

Answer (score 2):

This is a bit of a circular answer. But... if you need to do a lot of these operations, you can catalyze it. Given the phase gradient state $|0\rangle + e^{i 2 \pi / 3} |1\rangle + e^{i 4 \pi / 3} |2\rangle$ you can apply a controlled mod 3 increment to get phase kickback of exactly 120 degrees onto the control.

If you decompose the Toffolis inline, using 7 T gates each, two T gates will cancel and you'll use 12 T gates. If you can do measurement with feedback you can instead decompose the Toffolis using 4 T gates each.

[image]

Of course, to get the phase gradient state in the first place, you have to have done the operation you're trying to do. My point is that, instead of directly applying the operation each time, you can do it the hard way twice to make this particular state and then the cost suddenly drops because catalysis becomes possible.