# Which phase gates can be catalyzed by Clifford+Toffoli circuits with post-selection?

Tags: magic-states, zh-calculus

$\newcommand{\ket}[1]{|#1\rangle}$Let us call some state $k$-qubit state $\ket{S}$ catalyzable by some other state $\ket{S'}$ if there is a Clifford+Toffoli circuit (possibly with ancilla and/or post-selection), that transforms $\ket{S} \otimes \ket{0}^{\otimes k} \otimes \ket{S'}$ to $\ket{S} \otimes \ket{S} \otimes \ket{S'}$. For instance, the $\ket{T}$ magic state is catalyzable by the state $\ket{0}$:

[image: T gate catalysis]

Note that the restriction to Clifford+Toffoli circuits is arbitrary, and we could also work with Clifford+T. From now on, I will use the [ZH-calculus](https://arxiv.org/abs/1805.02175) (a graphical calculus related to ZX-calculus) to express some identities as it yields more compact expressions - all the ZH-diagrams given here can in principle be translated to Clifford+Toffoli circuits with ancilla. The identity above is a special case of the fact that by consuming a $\ket{Z_\alpha} = \ket{0} + e^{i\alpha}\ket{1}$ state, we can transform $\ket{Z_{\alpha/2}}$ into $\ket{Z_{\alpha/2}}\otimes \ket{Z_{\alpha/2}}$:

[image: general Zalpha catalysis]

Since $\ket{T} = \ket{Z_{\pi/4}}$ and $\ket{Z_{\pi/2}} = SH\ket{0}$ can be prepared by a Clifford circuit, this can be used to 'bootstrap' the catalysis. These $\ket{Z_\alpha}$ states are significant because they can be used to create a $Z_\alpha$ phase-gate by magic state injection. Note that catalysis is kind of transitive - if $\ket{S} \otimes \ket{S'}$ can be transformed to $\ket{S} \otimes \ket{S}$ by a Clifford+Toffoli circuit $C$, and $\ket{S'}$ is catalyzed by $\ket{S''}$ with a circuit $C'$, then $\ket{S}$ can be catalyzed by $\ket{S'} \otimes \ket{S''}$:

[image: transitivity]

This implies that the states $\ket{Z_{\pi/ 2^k}}$ for $k > 2$ are also catalyzable, by the state $\ket{Z_{\pi/2^{k - 1}}} \otimes \cdots \otimes \ket{Z_{\pi/4}} \otimes \ket{0}$. In fact, we can generalize the construction that transforms $\ket{Z_{\alpha/2}} \otimes \ket{Z_\alpha}$ into $\ket{Z_{\alpha/2}} \otimes \ket{Z_{\alpha/2}}$ to operate on the unnormalized states $\ket{H_a} = \ket{0} + a\ket{1}$ (so $\ket{Z_\alpha} = \ket{H_{e^{i\alpha}}}$ - in ZH-calculus, these are H-boxes with one wire):

[image: hbox catalysis]

And so we can transform $\ket{H_\sqrt{a}} \otimes \ket{H_a}$ into $\ket{H_\sqrt{a}} \otimes \ket{H_\sqrt{a}}$. Using a Clifford+Toffoli circuit, we can also construct $\ket{H_{a + b}}$ and $\ket{H_{ab}}$ from $\ket{H_a}$ and $\ket{H_b}$:

[image: addition gadgets]

Similar constructions exist for $\ket{H_{a - b}}$ and $\ket{H_{a / b}}$. We can also construct $\ket{H_k}$ directly for any $k \in \mathbb{N}$ (for example, see [this paper by Backens et al](https://arxiv.org/abs/2103.06610)), as well as $\ket{H_i} = SH\ket{0}$. This leads to the following result:

**Theorem 1**: $\ket{Z_\alpha}$ is catalyzable by some state $\ket{S}$ if $\alpha$ is an angle that can be constructed by straightedge and compass.

Proof: Since we can construct the integers, addition, multiplication, subtraction, and division with Clifford+Toffoli circuits, and square roots by introducing an extra catalyst qubit, any $a$ that can be constructed out of these operations starting from integers
has $\ket{H_{a}}$ catalyzable. It is a famous result of Gauss and Wantzel that such numbers $a$ are exactly those such that the real and imaginary parts can be constructed by a straightedge and compass.

This means that quite a broad class of $\ket{Z_\alpha}$ are catalyzable, including $\ket{Z_{\pi/2^k}}$, $\ket{Z_{\pi/3}}$ (see [this answer by Craig Gidney](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/23347/20303), for example), $\ket{Z_{\pi/5}}$, etc. Now we can, finally, get to my actual questions:

**Question 1**: Is the converse of Theorem 1 true, or are there non-constructible angles which are catalyzable? (The smallest possible counterexample would be $\frac{\pi}{7}$, but I haven't found anything in the literature about this)

**Question 2**: In general, if $\ket{Z_\alpha}$ is catalyzable, is $\ket{Z_{\alpha / 3}}$ also catalyzable? (This does not follow from the construction above because it is impossible to trisect a general angle with a straightedge and compass)

**Question 3**: What about other divisors, or even other functions of $\alpha$ - if $\ket{Z_\alpha}$ is catalyzable, for what $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ can $\ket{Z_{f(\alpha)}}$ be catalyzed?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Why wouldn't pi/7 be possible? The same trick used for pi/3 would work for it. Any rational fraction of a turn can be achieved that way.

Comment: You're aware of hamming weight phasing?

Comment: @CraigGidney I was not aware of it, but now I've read some about it, it doesn't seem to quite solve the problem since you need to construct the angles Z(2*theta), Z(4*theta), etc. In the case of theta = pi/2^k, that works out nicely, when theta = pi/q, it seems like I'd need q copies of this gadget in the worst case where 2 is a generator mod  q. That's okay, but I'd prefer a solution that was polynomial in log q. I'll look into adapting the pi/3 construction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has a lot to do with work that my colleagues and I [presented at QIP in 2022](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G_ioa2fCjSc&ab_channel=QIP2022), with the first of this series of papers now available [on arXiv](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2305.07720.pdf). In particular, in the linked paper we show that a particularly nice way that you can catalytically embed a unitary operation over a Kroneckerian ring (number ring in which you can unambiguously define complex conjugation) into one of its subrings is by constructing a special matrix called a *normal pseudo companion matrix* (basically, a normal matrix whose characteristic polynomial is a power of the minimal polynomial) for a particular element of the larger ring over the subring.

In the talk I mention that we have a way to construct these matrices whenever we deal with fields, and the resulting constructions are essentially as good as possible. That paper is currently being edited to be more in line with the language of the linked arXiv paper, and I hope that we can put it up sometime in the coming month(s). All of this to say - you can pretty much catalyze any state whose entries are elements of a Kroneckerian number field via Clifford + T.

Comment: Thanks, I'll be sure to keep an eye out for the constructions paper. Also, great talk - "catalysis means gate sets are equivalent up to a change of basis" is a very neat intuition.